# android make listitem height smaller

Tags: android, android-listview

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup vg) {
    DateTimeRangeViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        view = View.inflate(getContext(),
                R.layout.adapter_item_board_time_dialog, null);
        holder = new DateTimeRangeViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (DateTimeRangeViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    Date itemDate = items.get(pos);
    holder.tv1.setText(sdf.format(itemDate));
    holder.tv2.setText(sdf.format(itemDate));

    return view;
}

private class DateTimeRangeViewHolder {
    final TextView tv1;
    final TextView tv2;

    DateTimeRangeViewHolder(View view) {
        tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    }
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/board_time_dialog_main_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/board_time_dialog_main_padding"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_16" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/text1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_14" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With any minHeight it is not working! Even if I set height for layout in code my layout has this height but whole listitem has the unchangable height.
[image: picture]

There are a lot of questions the same as my but I can't find answer. No one of the answers works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with how you are inflating your views, since you are not providing information about the parent view.

Change how you are inflating your views to: `View.inflate(getContext(),        R.layout.adapter_item_board_time_dialog, vg);`

Also, since you want to SIZE DOWN the view, you should specific a `android:maxHeight` on your `RelativeLayout`, not a `android:minHeight`, if you bother specifying one at all.

Comment: I tried both of your advices but there is no success